# didSelectRow not registering well cell touch

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, touch, cell

didSelectRow is only registering touch action on cell if an empty space in cell is tapped. If user accidentally taps the label or image view which are in cell, the didSelectRow does not register. How would one fix this, so that any space tapped in cell would register?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is something else capturing the taps? A button?

Comment: no, just "func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)"

Comment: I just did a very simple test of a table app and it is working for me. You are going to have to upload code and possibly your entire project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess without seeing your code/interface is that you need to make sure userInteractionEnabled is set to false on all of the cell's subviews. If not, those views will capture the touch and it will not reach the cell's view.